# Limit zoom on DateTime axis

Tags: wpf, datetime, wpf-controls, scichart

I am using SciChart with DateTimeAxis.

My items are starting from 15 May 2016 8:30 AM and ending on 25 May 2016 8:30 AM. Initial value of VisibleRange is set this this range as well. I have also added VisibleRangeLimit again with same range.

But the problem is that when I am scrolling to corners, date values are going out of my range and, as a result, on some zoom levels I see dates out of my allowed range, like 15 May 2016 8:25 AM. This is causing to blank are for 5 minutes.

Is there any way to really limit visible range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is,

From the [Documentation: Clipping the Axis.VisibleRange on Zoom and Pan](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#Axis%20Ranging%20-%20Clipping%20VisibleRange.html).

> Advanced VisibleRange Clipping and Manipulation
>
> [Axis.VisibleRangeLimit](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.AxisBase~VisibleRangeLimit.html) is a useful API to ensure the axis clips the [VisibleRange](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.AxisCore~VisibleRange.html) when zooming to extents. However, it will not stop a user from scrolling outside of that range. To achieve that, you need a small modification:
>
> Clipping Axis.VisibleRange in Code
>
> To clip the [VisibleRange](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.AxisCore~VisibleRange.html) and force a certain maximum or minimum, just use the following code:
>
> ```csharp
> axis.VisibleRangeChanged += (s, e) =>
> {
>    // e is VisibleRangeChangedEventArgs
>    // Assuming axis is NumericAxis
>
>    if (e.NewVisibleRange != null && e.NewVisibleRange.Min < 0)
>    {
>       // Force minimum visiblerange to zero always
>       ((NumericAxis)sender).VisibleRange = new DoubleRange(0, e.NewVisibleRange.Max);
>    }
> };
> ```
>
> Clipping Axis.VisibleRange with MVVM
>
> The same can be achieved in MVVM by creating a custom behavior.
>
> ```csharp
> public class AxisClippingBehavior : Behavior<AxisBase>
>   {
>     protected override void OnAttached()
>     {
>         base.OnAttached();
>
>         AssociatedObject.VisibleRangeChanged +=OnVisibleRangeChanged;
>     }
>
>     protected override void OnDetaching()
>     {
>         base.OnDetaching();
>
>         AssociatedObject.VisibleRangeChanged -= OnVisibleRangeChanged;
>     }
>
>     private void OnVisibleRangeChanged(object sender, VisibleRangeChangedEventArgs visibleRangeChangedEventArgs)
>     {
>         var visibleRangeLimit = AssociatedObject.VisibleRangeLimit;
>         if (visibleRangeLimit != null)
>         {
>             var limitMode = AssociatedObject.VisibleRangeLimitMode;
>
>             var range = (IRange)AssociatedObject.VisibleRange.Clone();
>             range.ClipTo(visibleRangeLimit, limitMode);
>
>             AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(AxisBase.VisibleRangeProperty, range);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already tried this solution but it have one issue. When you scroll to left it is starting to change zoom level, when min value is becoming limited min one. I was thinking there may be other solution. So in order to fix mentioned issue max value also needs to be corrected by adding (axis.visiblerangelimit.min - e.NewVisibleRange.Min) to  e.NewVisibleRange.Max.
I will mark this item as solved, but please update answer with this patch. Thanks

Comment: Hi Samvel, I'm glad it's working, but I'm not quite sure the needed change. Do you want to edit my answer? (Do you have permissions).

Comment: I just suggested to update for other users, as they also may have mentioned issue.